# ASP.NET Core 3.1 "Unsupported handler method return type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList'"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, selectlist, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

As soon as set the return type of a function as **SelectList** I get this error:
**Unsupported handler method return type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList'**

```
        public SelectList OnGetCategories()
        {
            //whatever
            return null;
            
        }
```

The body of function does not matter.

I even do not use the function, being the function in the code is enough for raising error.

**SelectList** or **Null** output does not matter.

This code was working in ASP.NET Core 2.2 without any error and I could call it by jQuery Ajax to retrieve my categories in a proper format.

Comment: Change it to `public IActionResult OnGetCategories(){ ...  return new JsonResult(items);  }`

Comment: @itminus Thank you, What's the problem with my code?

Comment: My best guess is: your code never worked in ASP.NET Core 2.2 **RazorPage**. You remembered it incorrectly. Actually it does work on ASP.NET Core **MVC**  no matter in 2.2 or 3.1. Anyway, if you're using RazorPage, change it to return an IActionResult/void

Comment: @itminus believe me it's working now on 2.2, due to an issue I decided to convert it to 3.1 and then it raised an Error, anyway I'm going to check your code, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what is suggested by [@itminus in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486375/asp-net-core-3-1-unsupported-handler-method-return-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-m/69899501#comment105164343_59486375):

```cs
public IActionResult OnGetCategories() 
{ 
    return new JsonResult(result); 
}
```

Comment: Really? Copied comment from two years ago?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: I think elevating a comment to an answer is acceptable, though it should obviously acknowledge credit. I’ve edited it to acknowledge the previous contribution. (That said, when I do this, I usually post it as a community wiki, since it’s not my original contribution.)

Comment: Sorry I missed out the credit...

Thank you @JeremyCaney for pointing this out...